# does map().take() reexecute when based on ReplaySubject.asObservable()

Tags: rxjs

I have a `ReplaySubject` with a buffer size of 1. I am wondering if, when mapping an observable created from calling `let observable = subject.asObservable()` whether or not the following composition re-executes for each new buffer.

```
observable.map((nextThing) => {
   console.log(nextThing, 'got one!');
 }).take(1)
```

given a stream of `Observable<string>`'s like `"Hey", "Jey" "Fley"` would the only output be `"Heygot one!"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Hey got one!"` is all that will be logged.

As soon as `take` receives the first value, it completes and unsubscribes - which sees `map` unsubscribe, too:

```js
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
const observable = subject.asObservable();

observable
  .map((nextThing) => console.log(nextThing, 'got one!'))
  .take(1)
  .subscribe();

subject.next('Hey');
subject.next('Jey');
subject.next('Fley');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `take` will receive `undefined`, as `map` is not returning a value.